# In swift, when append model in modelArray , counts shows nil

Tags: arrays

NewSellLocalDataModel() this is model class,
newsellData?.data.productDetails?.varients.append(contentsOf: variants) and when append on this array , array count show nil.

Comment: Please tag the appropriate language tags to get the right attention.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare newSellData as an optional you cannot append to it until you initialise as an empty array:

```
var newsellData: NewSellLocalDataModel?

...

newsellData = NewSellLocalDataModel() // initialise
newsellData?.data.productDetails?.varients.append(contentsOf: variants) // This will now show a non-nil count
```

Comment: I have implement the same but still getting nil after append.

Comment: Please show more code.